# Is there a way to remove node numbers from fancyRpartPlot?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rattle

Hey hoping someone can tell me how to remove the node numbers from just above the boxes when using the fancyrpartplot function from rattle, they sometimes overlap with the variable labels. Tried nn = FALSE which is supposed to be passed to prp but no luck,

Thanks

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)
library(survival)

fancyRpartPlot(
  rpart(Surv(futime, death) ~ age, data = mgus2, cp = 0.002),
  type = 4, 
  cex = 0.75,
  split.col = "#34495e", 
  branch.col = "#34495e", 
  caption = "",
  palettes= "Reds"
  )
```